# Get href from an element found by ID - Python - Selenium

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium

This is my code:

```
dispatch_button = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'alarm')]")
href = dispatch_button.get_attribute('href')
print(href)
```

This is the HTML i'm working with:

```
<a href="/missions/12357831" class="btn btn-default btn-xs lightbox-open" id="alarm_button_12357831"> Dispatch</a>
```

The ID and href both contain a number that changes which is why i'm finding it using the partial ID.

I'm completely stumped as i can't see why I'm getting this error:

```
 href = dispatch_button.get_attribute('href')
 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
```

I'm trying to locate the dispatch_button by its partial ID, and then use its href.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get single WebElement you should use `find_element_by_xpath()` instead of `find_elements_by_xpath()`:

```
dispatch_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'alarm')]")
href = dispatch_button.get_attribute('href')
```

or if you want to handle multiple elements matched by specified selector:

```
dispatch_buttons = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'alarm')]")
hrefs = [dispatch_button.get_attribute('href') for dispatch_button in dispatch_buttons]
```

Also you can try to locate required anchor by `link_text`:

```
dispatch_button = browser.find_element_by_link_text("Dispatch")
```

Comment: Welcome. You can accept the answer if it solved your issue